# C++ 2d char array to string

Tags: c++, arrays, char

How can you convert a 2d char array into a string?

```
 int main()
{
   char foo[3][3] = {{'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'}};
   string bar;
   bar = foo;
   cout<< bar; //abcdefghi

 return 0;
}
```

also can you convert only select parts of a 2d array to a string?

```
 int main()
{
   char foo[3][3] = {{'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'}};
   string bar;
   bar = foo[0][1] + foo[1][2] + foo[2][0];
   cout<< bar; //bfg (bar contains only b, f, and g)

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of only showing what you want, please show us what you have *tried*.

Comment: `also can you convert only select parts of a 2d array to a string`can you explain this a lil more

Comment: Iv spent the last 2 hours trying strcpy,strcat,strncat,memcpy and every other possible thing I could think of and nothing works. Iv tried googleing for it and there are thousands of "convert string to 2d array" tutorials but I cant find a single one showing how to do 2darray to string.

Comment: _'trying strcpy,strcat,strncat,...'_ Those may have failed because of the missing `'\0'` terminators in the 2nd array level.

Comment: +1 for spending 2 hours :)

Comment: Acually if you want to use **memcpy** I belive you can do something like this: `char string[9];
memcpy(&string[0], &foo[0]);
memcpy(&string[3], &foo[1]);
memcpy(&string[6], &foo[2]);` And can also use a loop to make it more dynamic, although this way is kinda inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this piece of code will help, welcome to c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char foo[3][3] = {{'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'}};
   string bar;
   bar = "";
   for(int i =0 ; i< 3;i++)
   {
      for(int j =0 ;j<3;j++)
      {
          bar += foo[i][j];
      }
   }
   cout<< bar; //abcdefghi

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `using namespace`; no need from `bar = "";`; you can use `std::string::reserve` to increase performance; I'd use `std::string::append` instead. Just opinion.

Comment: I had no idea you could simply set a string equal to a char array. Thank you.

Comment: @user3331346 _'set a string equal to a char array'_ That's not what the add operation (`bar += foo[i][j];`) does!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand the += is appending the value of foo and not setting bar equal to the value of foo. What I meant was I was under the impression that the only way to convert a char to a string was to use some function like strcpy. I did not think it would be possible to just string = char. I am very new to C++.

Comment: @user3331346, it is actually the operator +=, and it char each time it is added see the definition here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/

Answer (score 7):

You can use the fact that the elements in the 2D array are contiguous, and [the two-iterator constructor of `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
char foo[3][3] = {{'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'}};
std::string bar(&foo[0][0], &foo[2][2]+1);
std::cout << bar << std::endl; // abcdefgi
```

Here, `&foo[0][0]` is a pointer to the first element, and `&foo[2][2] + 1` is a pointer to one past the last one. And pointers are iterators.

Comment: can you explain why not `&foo[2][2]` only?

Comment: @OmerObaid The second iterator is never included. For a given range, the second iterator is "one past the last". So `&foo[2][2]` would only copy `abcdefgh`.

Comment: @UnTraDe It is more that I am too lazy to write my own loops :-)

Comment: I was interested in why you did the &foo[2][2]+1 instead of just &foo[2][2] and I found this: `Input iterators to the initial and final positions in a range. The range used is [first,last), which includes all the characters between first and last, including the character pointed by first but not the character pointed by last.`
Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Might help others who try to figure this out.

Comment: @UnTraDe It is a common idiom in the standard library. I added a link to a `std::string` constructor reference. I think all the information is there.

Comment: Thanks I didn't knew that since I don't work a lot with the Standard Librery.

Comment: @UnTraDe You should become a lazy programmer, like me :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza And I probably will someday :)

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard does not contain a function to this, so you'll have to write your own.

You can use the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char foo[3][3] = {{'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'}};
    string bar;


    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            bar.append(foo[i][j]);
        }
    }

    cout << bar;

    return 0;
}
```

This code iterate through the 2d array, which is acually an array or arrays, and add each character to the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){

 Char ar[4][10]=. 
  {"one","two","three","four"};


      for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
           Cout<<ar[i]<<endl;

      }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).